# Display user list except the user who is logged in, quickblox ios

Tags: ios, quickblox

I have written a code in ios using and I am using the quickblox api for ios video chat:-

Here is my code:-

// Get Users result

```
- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{ 

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:[QBUUserPagedResult class]]){

    QBUUserPagedResult *usersResult = (QBUUserPagedResult *)result;
    NSLog(@"Users=%@", usersResult.users);
    NSLog(@"Page parameters: currentPage %lu, totalPages %lu, perPage %lu, totalEntries %lu",
       (unsigned long)usersResult.currentPage,
       (unsigned long)usersResult.totalPages,
       (unsigned long)usersResult.perPage,
       (unsigned long)usersResult.totalEntries);
    [noOfuser removeAllObjects];
    [noOfuser addObjectsFromArray:usersResult.users];

    for (int i=0; i<[noOfuser count];i++)
    {
        QBUUser *tmpUser=(QBUUser *)[noOfuser objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"bbbbb%@",tmpUser);
        if (appDelegate.currentUser==i) {
            [noOfuser removeObject:noOfuser[i]];
        }
    }
    [self.tblTeamList reloadData];
}else{
    NSLog(@"errors=%@", result.errors);} }
```

Here I am fetching the list of users who are added in my Quickblox application, but I don't want to display the name of the person in the list who is logged in, I want to display only users except the logged in user. Can you please check the code and correct me where I am going wrong.

Example:-

If I have four users named a,b,c,d in a group then when a is logged in then b,c,d should be displayed not a.

Answer (score 0):

```
QBUUser *currentUser = ...

...

if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:[QBUUserPagedResult class]]){
     QBUUserPagedResult *usersResult = (QBUUserPagedResult *)result;

     NSMutableArray *allUsers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:usersResult.users];

     NSMutableArray *allUsersCopy = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:allUsers];
     for(QBUUser *user in allUsersCopy){
         if(user.ID == currentUser.ID){
             [allUsers removeObject:user];
             break;
         }
     }

}
```

Next - use **allUsers** array - it doesn't contain your current user